# Why does it call wrong virtual function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, virtual

Why does this code call the wrong virtual function? It calls the one at offset 8 while it should be calling the one at offset 4. If I rename the function at 8 it correctly calls the one at 4. Code gen bug? Something silly I'm missing?

Source:

```
class surface_c
{
public:
    virtual ~surface_c() = 0; // 0
    virtual bool blit(int) = 0; // 4
    virtual bool blit() = 0; // 8
};

int main()
{
    surface_c* surface;
    surface->blit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Disassembly:

```
int main()
{
00A11250  push        ebp  
00A11251  mov         ebp,esp  
00A11253  sub         esp,44h  
00A11256  push        ebx  
00A11257  push        esi  
00A11258  push        edi  
    surface_c* surface;
    surface->blit(0);
00A11259  push        0  
00A1125B  mov         eax,dword ptr [surface]  
00A1125E  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
00A11260  mov         ecx,dword ptr [surface]  
00A11263  mov         eax,dword ptr [edx+8]  
00A11266  call        eax  
    return 0;
00A11268  xor         eax,eax  
}
00A1126A  pop         edi  
00A1126B  pop         esi  
00A1126C  pop         ebx  
00A1126D  mov         esp,ebp  
00A1126F  pop         ebp  
00A11270  ret
```

Comment: How can you know where `bool blit(int)` is located? I don't think the C++ standard says anything about vtable layout.

Comment: Btw, the beginning of vtable can contain something else, not virtual methods.

Comment: It means that `blit(int)` is at offset 8, not 4 as you believe.

Comment: @Tobias Right, how does VC2013 order the functions in the vtable? I know it's implementation defined. Normally I don't care, but this is a reverse engineering project (of the game Red Alert 2) and I need to match the original vtable layout.

Comment: Then maybe you should edit your question (or start a new one) to ask about VC's vtable layout.

Comment: you should have concrete implementation of methods is there any subclass with concrete implemenation

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    surface_c* surface; // surface contains garbage, as it is uninitialzed
    surface->blit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

surface must be pointing to some non-abstract subclass of surface_c, e.g.

```
surface = new surface_f();
```

where surface_f is some non-abstract subclass of surface_c, and the inherited pure virtual functions must be overridden by concrete implementations

Comment: It's about the generated assembly for the blit call. I know surface is uninitialized, it's merely there to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method on an uninitialized pointer. It is pure luck that a method is called, and the program does not crash.